# R - Categorizing column data by features of the header

Tags: r, categorization

Suppose that I have a dataframe with column headers coded in such a way as to give several pieces of information. For example, the first number represents "Group" while the second number represents "Day" and the associated values are some sort of count.

```
Species    1-0     1-1     1-2     2-0     2-1     2-2
Mouse      50      50      50      48      47      47
Rat        50      49      47      52      52      52
Hamster    49      40      35      50      45      43
```

Assuming that my list of species is quite long (<300), how would I go about categorizing the data according to each of the two pieces of information in order to analyze by column? So in this example, there are Groups 1 and 2, and Days 0, 1 and 2. I would eventually like to plot the average count for each time point in Group 1 vs. Group 2, regardless of species.

Answer (score 0):

You need some reshaping of your data in order to get the info of the column names and create different columns in your dataset.
Then calculate the means based on the grouping you want and finally plot the means.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(ggplot2)

    dt = read.table(text="
    Species    1_0     1_1     1_2     2_0     2_1     2_2
    Mouse      50      50      50      48      47      47
    Rat        50      49      47      52      52      52
    Hamster    49      40      35      50      45      43", header=T)

    # rename to get rid of "X" in the columns names
    names(dt) = gsub("X","",names(dt))   ## NOTE: maybe you don't have to do that, but for my example here I had to remove an extra "X" in my column names

    # transform column as character
    dt$Species = as.character(dt$Species)  ## NOTE: you don't really need this, as you mentioned you don't care for specific species, but just in case you want to include them in your analysis/grouping


    dt %>%
      gather(v,value,-Species) %>%               # create a column with the column names
      separate(v, into=c("group","day")) %>%     # separate the info
      group_by(group, day) %>%                   # for each group and day
      summarise(MeanValue = mean(value)) %>%     # calculate the mean
      mutate(day = as.numeric(day)) %>%          # day needs to be numeric for the plot
      ggplot(., aes(x=day, y=MeanValue, col=group))+
      geom_line()+
      geom_point()
```

It should look like this:

[image]